# How to get the full list of categories of "likes"?

Tags: facebook-like, categories

I need to get the full list of categories which appear in https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes. 
This is to build a mapping system based upon Facebook likes categories of an user and some other data.

Comment: Using what technology?  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Just hold your data in a dictionary or some list for each page in the /me/likes response

For example in Facepy

```
my_likes = graph.get('me/likes', page=True)

my_categories = []

for like in my_likes["data"]:
            my_categories.append(like["category"])

my_categories = set(my_categories)
```